# How to access Ruby method inside module and inside a class from another .rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know how would I go about accessing the methods in this module from another .rb file

```
module Decisioning
  module Decision
    class OfferProxy < FinanceApplication::Offer

    def my_method
     "some value"
    end

  end
 end
end
```

So how would I access my_method from another .rb file?

maby something like

> include ::Decisioning::Decision::OfferProxy

can I then use

> my_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably more like this:

```
module Decisioning
  module Decision
    class OfferProxy

    def self.my_method
     "some value"
    end

  end
 end
end

class TestFile

  include Decisioning::Decision

  def test
    puts OfferProxy.my_method
  end

end

TestFile.new.test
```

Or...

```
module Decisioning
  module Decision
    class OfferProxy

    def my_method
     "some value"
    end

  end
 end
end

class TestFile

  include Decisioning::Decision

  def test
    offer_proxy = OfferProxy.new
    puts offer_proxy.my_method
  end

end

TestFile.new.test
```