# Rails and modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a module for query objects. I created a file:

```
app/queries/invoices/edit.rb
```

with this class:

```
module Queries
  module Invoices
    class Edit
    end
  end
end
```

However, I can't initialize it:

```
2.3.3 :001 > Queries::Invoices::Edit.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Queries
```

When I omit the `Queries` module, everything works:

```
module Invoices
  class Edit
  end
end


2.3.3 :005 > Invoices::Edit.new
=> #<Invoices::Edit:0x007fc729e15558>
```

Why is that?

Comment: I don't think you need to call the chain of modules for initializing `Edit`. You can simply include it in a specific context and then just do `Edit.new`. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14855256/3284936

Comment: @Dimitry_N I don't want to use `include`. Rails autoloads everything from the `app/` directory anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first level under `app` isn't considered part of the namespace. It's why you don't say, for instance:

```
module Models
  class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

for a model like `app/models/foo.rb`.

If you want `Queries` in your namespace, you could do something like:

```
app/queries/queries/invoices/edit
```

But, that looks icky to me. I think I'd do something more like:

```
app/queries/invoice_queries/edit
```

and then:

```
module InvoiceQueries
  class Edit
  end
end
```

Comment: also you're violating Rails' conventions of singular naming in models and plural naming in Controllers. This will cause issues with the inflections.

Comment: @engineerDave - Say more, please?

Comment: @engineerDave: there are no models or controllers here. So I think it's fine :)

Comment: true but the module naming usually follows the singular model naming too. It might cause some issues if you ever need to use singularize or pluralize that's all I'm saying.

Comment: I may be reading it wrong, but it seems like rails uses plurals quite commonly for module names. For example: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord.html

Answer (score 1):

@jvillian's answer is correct. However, I don't like both choices :)

What I do in my projects is put all those custom object types into `app/lib`

```
app/lib/queries/invoices/edit.rb
app/lib/services/invoices/sync.rb
```

This way `lib` serves as that padding, which pushes `queries` to be part of namespace. Also, all your "non-standard" code is nicely contained in one directory.

Comment: I tried your way. I have `Queries::Invoices::Edit` class in `app/lib/queries/invoices/edit.rb` and there is the same problem. Dropping the `Querires` module works.

Comment: @pmichna Interesting. What's in your `autoload_paths`?

Comment: I haven't modified it, so it's the default for Rails 5. Running `bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` returns among others `my_project/app/queries`.

Comment: @pmichna Did you not remove `app/queries/invoices/edit.rb`?