# Loading module into User Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to make available the methods I have stored in a Module which is located in `app/models` (side note: not sure if this is the correct place for modules?).

Module:

```
module MyModule
    class MyClass
        def some_method
           # do something
        end
    end
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    
    include MyModule

    def another_method
       some_method
    end
end
```

I am getting a NoMethodError:
`NoMethodError (undefined method 'some_method' for #<User:0x00007f6a3ce452c0>`

Comment: If you remove `class MyClass` and the corresponding `end` your `User` model should work. See https://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html under the section `Mixins`

Comment: you can just define the method in the module without the class if that fit your usecase.

Comment: Thanks both, I'll check the documentation link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have missunderstood what what modules and classes do in Ruby. In Ruby a module is simply an object that wraps a set of methods and constants.

A module can *extend* other modules, classes and objects and can be included in classes thus implementing multiple inheritance. Modules in Ruby fill the role that traits, namespaces and singletons do in other languages.

Classes are actually modules (Module is part of the ancestors chain of Class) with the key difference that you can make instances of a class and that class can inherit from a single other class and cannot extend other objects or be included.

The code example here actually doesn't make sense. If you want to declare a method that will be available to classes that include a module you want to declare it in the module itself:

```
module MyModule
  def some_method
    # do something
  end
end
```

When you then call `User#another_method` it will look in the ancestors chain of the User class until it finds the method which is defined in `MyModule`.

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    def some_method
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

Will actually definte the class `MyClass` with an instance method that is only available to instances of `MyClass`. The only thing that the module does here is change the module nesting so that the class is defined in MyModule instead of the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks max, trying to answer this brought me to digging deeper into the concept of modules and I think that instead of putting a class inside a module, you can just simply add another module so you can then just include MainModule::ChildModule, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Thats correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mix in a method from a method into your class then just put the methods directly in the module (without an intermediate class).

Module:

```rb
module MyModule
  def some_method
    # do something
  end
end
```

User Model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include MyModule

  def another_method
    some_method
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14855256/13942090), you need to instantiate your Class first. Or if you want to

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    
    include MyModule

    def another_method
       my_instance = MyClass.new
       my_instance.some_method
    end
end
```

As for a place to store your Module, [have a look at this guide about service objects](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial), it gave me some inspiration when it comes to different modules.